# Jquery Slider fade automatically.

Tags: jquery, image, slider, jquery-slider

I'm working with this great example of a jQuery slider: http://papermashup.com/simple-jquery-gallery/

here is the Jquery:

```
$(function() {
$(".image").click(function() {
var image = $(this).attr("rel");
$('#image').hide();
$('#image').fadeIn('slow');
$('#image').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');
   return false;
   });
});
```

and here is the HTML

```
<div id="image"><img src="images/1.png" border="0"/></div>
<a href="#" rel="images/1.png" class="image"><img src="images/t1.png" class="thumb" border="0"/></a>
<a href="#" rel="images/2.png" class="image"><img src="images/t2.png" class="thumb" border="0"/></a>
<a href="#" rel="images/3.png" class="image"><img src="images/t3.png" class="thumb" border="0"/></a>
```

What I would like to know is, How can I get the large images to automatically be fading through the rest of them in a loop. And When I click one for it to start at that point. I plan to have around 20-ish images.

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is something called `setInterval(param1,param2)` method in JavaScript.

`param1`: Function that invokes the change of image.

`param2`: Time interval.

I dint bother to modify your example but I made my own example, out of which you can map the function in your example. Please check see this [**fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/kFGmC/29/)

Disclaimer: The images i used are only for demonstration purposes. I dont own any of those images.